# I'm not typing something right

Tags: c#

```
return Convert.ToInt32(myClass2.Digit(bmp, nX1, nY1)
                                 + myClass2.Digit(bmp, nX2, nY2)
                                 + myClass2.Digit(bmp, nX3, nY3)
                                 + myClass2.Digit(bmp, nX4, nY4)
                                 + myClass2.Digit(bmp, nX5, nY5));
```

...finds this test method:

```
class Class2 {
    public string Digit(Bitmap bmp, int x, int y) {
//Please drop any logic using bmp, x, and y for the sake of this post.  Let's just...
        return "3";
    }
}
```

and returns 33333 as an int.  As a preliminary to get something going so far, so good.

The problem comes when I want to return "0"; there's literally no output, not even an 0 much less an 00000.  Instead, a line isn't even written to the console.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: I don't see your code writing anything to the console...

Comment: Try isolating the code. This: `int t = Convert.ToInt32("000000");` produces `0`; so your problem is somewhere else.

Comment: And show the (test)code with the 0's

Comment: Well, you _won't_ get `00000` since you're converting it to an integer, which cares little for leading zeros. However, you _should_ get `0`. All I can say is to listen to Ignacio and post some more code.

Comment: I haven't written any other logic in Class2 yet. All I have is it returning a string "0" that is subsequently concatenated with the +'s. I thought that would be sufficent to have five of those elements pushed together into a five char string. The problem is 0 isn't being treated as such while 1-9 are. Mystifying, at least to me.

Comment: Please show a short but complete program which demonstrates the problem. You haven't shown how you're using this, or any code which *actually* returns 0s.

Comment: Okay, I got it working by Consoling it from within an intermediate step, rather than the main routine, so I'll work it out. Thanks--very much--for all the assistance.

Comment: paxdiablo, great answer, thanks. That's what I get doing this at 4 AM.

Answer (score 1):

If you want leading zeros use this:

```
Console.WriteLine(String.Format("00000", someInteger));
```

Comment: Please explain why it is not working and what the solution is. We want this forum to be useful for others too.

Comment: The code as originally posted proved in the final analysis to be fine. pax above got me back on track.

Comment: Ok. Then please add the answer or mark the answer to indicate that the question has been answered.

Comment: When the problem has been solved there should be an answer (not a comment marked as being the accepted answer. If there is a comment that fixed it or you fixed it yourself add an answer (not a comment) and mark it as the accepted answer. This will make it easier for others to find the solution without digging through all of the comments. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Solved.  My code as originally posted proved in the final analysis to be fine.  Question is moot.